# Is it okay to send messages to the Nobody Instance actor? Are there any side-effects?

Tags: c#, akka.net

I want to use the Null Object pattern with the Nobody instance actor.
Under certain conditions my code would end up sending thousands of messages to the Nobody actor.

I'm well aware that the Nobody instance is commonly used to test against a look up failure, to compare if an actor exists or not.

Intended usage:

```
m_keepAliveActor = configuration.KeepAliveActor.Enabled ?
 Context.ActorOf(Props.Create<KeepAliveActor>()) : 
 Nobody.Instance;
....
m_keepAliveActor.Tell(workItem);
```

I'd expect to have negligible impact.

Is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly safe to send messages to the `ActorRefs.Nobody` actor - those messages will be reported as `Deadletter`s but there's no harm.